# multiple RewriteCond and RewriteRule in sequence

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2

I trying to build RewriteCond and rewriteRules such that they work in IF-ELSE condition type. I am adding rewiriteconds and rules in apache2.conf. But looks like, the rules are not getting executed. 
Here is what I have tried:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^Set-Cookie$
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://abc.xyz.com/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} ^Set-Cookie$
RewriteRule ^/([^/]*\.nff).*$ /srv/samba/FilesIN/$1
```

Cond/rules (As per my understanding)
If there is NO Set-Cookie then redirect to abc.xyz.com else 
direct to /srv/samba/FilesIN/$1

Please suggest if these Cond/Rules are correct ?

Thanks,
-Suresh

Comment: Is that your cookie name `Set-Cookie`? And it doesn't have any value set?

Comment: Yes, Set-Cookie is name of the cookie and it will have a value.

Answer (score 0):

Don't match `%{HTTP_COOKIE}` on just the name. Relax the regex boundaries to cover cookie value.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*Set-Cookie.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://abc.xyz.com/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} ^.*Set-Cookie.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+\.nff).*$ /srv/samba/FilesIN/$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks Ravi..i tried but still the requests are not coming to abc.xyz.com.

Comment: Is mod_rewrite enabled? Remove the first `RewriteCond` and check if you get redirected. If not, there's some other problem.

Answer (score 0):

The issue been resolved now. The rewritecond and rules should be in Virtualhost file and not in http.conf or apache.conf.